# CSRF Protection using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

Is there a way to implement only CSRF protection using spring security without using rest of the features like authentication and authorization ?

I tried the following configuration but it turns off all the features of spring-security. Wanted to see if there is a way to configure to leave the csrf features ON.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" security="none"/>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="Password1" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: This question doesn't really meet the guidelines for this site where you are expected to ask something specific.  Have you googled for a result already?  If so, then you should have tried something and have specific questions on that.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same requirement as you , and I was able to achieve it by minimal configurations in **spring-security.xml**

```
<authentication-manager />
<http create-session="never" use-expressions="true">
    <csrf />
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

Here the < authentication-manager /> declares that the spring security doesn't expect an authentication/authorization mechanism, and assumes that all requests are already authenticated.

After this add the Spring Security Filter on your **web.xml** file.  This ensures that all requests first pass through spring security mechanism before being handled by the application controller.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then in your JSPs (preferably the Header JSP), include the Spring Security's Taglib to access and store the CSRF tokens in the meta tag.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>

<sec:csrfMetaTags />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
</script>
```

After this include the CSRF Tokens in all your Ajax calls.  If not included, you will get the 403 - Access Denied Error.

For Example, if you are using jQuery for doing ajax calls, then you can configure it globally to include the CSRF tokens in the Request Header.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(csrfHeader, csrfToken);
});
```

JAR files required for this to work are:

```
    spring-security-acl-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-config-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-taglibs-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
```